# Scrapy LinkExtractor - Limit the number of pages crawled per URL

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, limit

I am trying to limit the number of crawled pages per URL in a CrawlSpider in Scrapy. I have a list of start_urls and I want to set a limit on the numbers pages are being crawled in each URL. Once the limit is reached, the spider should move to the next start_url.

I know there is the DEPTH_LIMIT parameter on setting but this is not what I am looking for.

Any help will be useful.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = domainvarwebsite
    start_urls = httpvarwebsite

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(),
             callback='parse_item',
             follow=True)
            ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #here I parse and yield the items I am interested in.
```

**EDIT**

I have tried to implement this, but I get  `exceptions.SyntaxError: invalid syntax (filter_domain.py, line 20)` . Any ideas of what is going on?

thanks again.

**filter_domain.py**

```
import urlparse
from collections import defaultdict
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

class FilterDomainbyLimitMiddleware(object):
def __init__(self, domains_to_filter):
    self.domains_to_filter = domains_to_filter
    self.counter = defaultdict(int)

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    settings = crawler.settings
    spider_name = crawler.spider.name
    max_to_filter = settings.get('MAX_TO_FILTER')
    o = cls(max_to_filter)
    return o

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(request.url)
    (LINE 20:) if self.counter.get(parsed_url.netloc, 0) < self.max_to_filter[parsed_url.netloc]):
        self.counter[parsed_url.netloc] += 1
    else:
        raise IgnoreRequest()
```

**settings.py**

```
MAX_TO_FILTER = 30

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.filter_domain.FilterDomainbyLimitMiddleware' :400,

}
```

Comment: There is a leading ')' before the ':' at line 20.

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy doesn't offer this directly, but you could create a custom Middleware, something like this:

```
import urlparse
from collections import defaultdict
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

class FilterDomainbyLimitMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, domains_to_filter):
        self.domains_to_filter = domains_to_filter
        self.counter = defaultdict(int)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        settings = crawler.settings
        spider_name = crawler.spider.name
        domains_to_filter = settings.get('DOMAINS_TO_FILTER')
        o = cls(domains_to_filter)
        return o

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(request.url)
        if parsed_url.netloc in self.domains_to_filter:
            if self.counter.get(parsed_url.netloc, 0) < self.domains_to_filter[parsed_url.netloc]):
                self.counter[parsed_url.netloc] += 1
            else:
                raise IgnoreRequest()
```

and declaring the `DOMAINS_TO_FILTER` in settings like:

```
DOMAINS_TO_FILTER = {
    'mydomain': 5
}
```

to only accept 5 requests from that domain. Also remember to enable the middleware in settings like specified [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#activating-a-downloader-middleware)

Comment: Great! How can I modify your code to set a fixed amount of requests no matter which domain it is? So that I just have to write a MAX_REQUESTS = 5 on settings.py?

Comment: Remove the first if in process_request

Comment: I tried to modify it but I get an error. I have edited my question to put the current code I am using.