# Limiting scrapy Request and Items

Tags: scrapy

everyone, I've been learning scrapy for a month. I need assistance with following problems:

1. Suppose there are 100-200 urls and I use Rule to extract further links from those urls and I want to limit the request of those links, like maximum 30 requests for each url. Can I do that?
2. If I'm searching a keyword on all urls, If the word is found on particular url, then I want scrapy to stop searching from that url and move to next one.

I've tried limiting url but it doesn't work at all.

Thanks, i hope everything is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`process_links` callback](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule) function with your Rule, this will be passed the list of extracted links from each response, and you can trim it down to your limit of 30.

Example (untested):

```py
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ['example.org']
    rules = ( 
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), process_links="dummy_process_links"),
    )   

    def dummy_process_links(self, links):
        links = links[:30]
        return links
```

---

If I understand correctly, and you want stop after finding some *word* in the page of the response, all you need to do is find the word:

```py
def my_parse(self, response):
    if b'word' is in response.body:
        offset = response.body.find(b'word')
        # do something with it
```

Comment: Thanks, can you provide me a rough example of process_links, i've never used it. For 2nd question, for example www.abc.com and www.xyz.com are url, it extracts 30 links from each url, the word 'abc' is found on lets say 3rd link of first url, if the word is found i want scrapy to jump to next url and ignore remaining links of firs url.

Comment: @AhmadAminFarooq, I added a small example. I still don't quite get the second one, are you looking for words _in_ the URL, or in the _response_ of the URL?

Comment: Thanks for the example, i'll try that. I'm looking for word in the response of the url.

Comment: Nope, I don't think it's working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452788/scrapy-linkextractor-limit-the-number-of-pages-crawled-per-url Iike this one, can you look into it?

Comment: I've found the word on certain url's domain response, but it keeps finding the word on same domain's url , i want it to move to another domain url . I hope i'm clear now

Comment: Sadly, no, sorry. I think you'll need to figure that out on your own, then.